# How to pipe the result of "ngrok http 8000" to another file?

Tags: python, bash, sh, ngrok

I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) for testing webhooks, and I find myself constantly copy/pasting the newly generated ngrok host into several places, so I decided to automate this process, but can't seem to find a clean way to extract the url from the ngrok process.

I expected to be able to pipe the output to a file, then extract it using regex or something, but the **`stdout`** appears to be empty.

For example, the following command results in an empty file: `ngrok http 8000 > test.txt`

This is the output of **`ngrok http 8000`**:

[image: output of ngrok http 8000]

I managed to find a *hack* using python+selenium and ngrok's "inspect":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

def main():
    opts = Options()
    opts.headless = True
    bot = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
    bot.get('http://localhost:4040/inspect/http')
    url_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/a'
    WebDriverWait(bot, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, url_xpath)))
    url = bot.find_element_by_xpath(url_xpath).text
    print(url.partition('://')[2])
    bot.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But this is slow, and a ton of code for something so trivial.  Also, it doesn't account from ngrok randomly changing the inspect port.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In general, programs that are intended to write _to a terminal_ expect to actually have a real TTY attached to their stdout; when you set up a pipeline, that's no longer the case. It's more conventional to have an explicitly-developed form of simplified output that's easy to grep/process/etc. provided when there isn't a teletype attached, instead of just pretending there was one... but of course, software support for providing that interface is a feature that `ngrok` would need to actually have implemented.

Comment: That said... I don't know exactly what ngrok is/does, but if what you're trying to do is monitor open network connections, this smells a lot like something that `sysdig` could do at least as well, and with easily-parsed JSON output available.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ngrok is just a tunnel to the net, allowing you to bypass NATs and firewalls, with some useful debugging features.  Also, what did you mean by "provided there isn't a teletype attached"?

Comment: "teletype" is in this context a somewhat antiquated word for "terminal". Something for which `isatty` returns true, which is true if you don't redirect to a file or pipeline and your stdout is defaulting to a... well... _terminal_, but false if either variety of redirection happens.

Comment: Whereas a lot of TTY functionality can be accessed just by sending the right escape sequences, that's not true of everything -- there are still features for which specific `ioctl()` calls -- ones which generally aren't available for things that aren't truly TTYs -- are necessary. See `stty` as an example of a program that exists to do such calls; your curses-style libraries, such as whichever one ngrok uses for its terminal handling, presumably does them under-the-hood when necessary.

Comment: BTW, one trick you might find useful is to wrap your software in something that emulates a terminal. The `unbuffer` tool from the `expect` package, for example.

Comment: I never used grok but I checked it's documentation.  Look at the `console_ui` option in the configuration file, `iftty` might do the trick for your need.  `log_format` also provides `logftm` and `json` options.  These control the format of the output and logs, and covers what @CharlesDuffy mentionned in his 1st post.  ah, even the `log` option allows you to specify the log filename.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of get result output from `ngrok http <port>`, you can use [agent api](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-agent/api#request).

Like screenshot in your question, when you execute ngrok http proxy, ngrok serves **Web Interface** (http://127.0.0.1:4040 in this case.)

This, Web Interface also support some APIs including able to retrieve public url (this is what you want).

After execute ngrok, try `curl http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/` than result json will be like below.

```json
{"tunnels":[{"name":"command_line","ID":"361e06eef2409dfeb996134e0b004f35","uri":"/api/tunnels/command_line","public_url":"https://0cdc-222-111-197-23.jp.ngrok.io","proto":"https","config":{"addr":"http://localhost:8080","inspect":true},"metrics":{"conns":{"count":0,"gauge":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0},"http":{"count":0,"rate1":0,"rate5":0,"rate15":0,"p50":0,"p90":0,"p95":0,"p99":0}}}],"uri":"/api/tunnels"}
```

Unfortunately, because response is in json format, parse and get public_url is needed. I recommend using parsing tools like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

for example,

```bash
curl http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels/ | jq .tunnels[0].public_url
# will prints "https://0cdc-222-111-197-23.jp.ngrok.io"
```